# Cannot get enableSnapshots working in SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to use 
`schedule_result = SL.instance(sl_config).net.enableSnapshots({
            'scheduleType' : 'DAILY',
            'retentionCount' : '20',
            'minute' : '1',
            'hour' : '13'
        },id=volume_ids[0])`

But returns `Error: faultCode=SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue, faultString=Invalid value provided for 'retentionCount'. Cannot keep zero or fewer snapshots.  Please use the disableSnapshots method to disable a snapshot schedule.`

Is this a known breakage in the SL Api, or am I misusing?

Answer (score 0):

The [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::enableSnapshots](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/enableSnapshots) method receives parameters, in this case you are sending all of these parameters as an object (that was the mistake). Also the **retentionCount**, **minute** and **hour** parameters should be send as integer datatypes.

Please try the following python script or send the values as parameters:

```
"""
This script enables snapshots.  This method is not valid for Legacy iSCSI Storage Volumes.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/enableSnapshots

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

"""
Your SoftLayer API username and key.
"""
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare a new API service for SoftLayer_Network_Storage
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
storageService = client['Network_Storage']

# Define the storage's identifier
storageId = 123123

# Define parameters for snapshot
scheduleType = 'DAILY'
retentionCount = 20
minute = 1
hour = 13

try:
    result = storageService.enableSnapshots(scheduleType, retentionCount, minute, hour, id=storageId)
    print (result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Error: "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```